# VB.net - Progressbar using BackgroundWorker

Tags: .net, vb.net, progress-bar, backgroundworker

I am trying to implement a progressbar using BackgroundWorker.

**But the progress bar hides itself after a second and it doesn't remain on top till end. Not sure why.**

Below is my code in form:

```
Private Sub btnProgressBarPOC_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnProgressBarPOC.Click
    BackgroundWorker = New BackgroundWorker()
    BackgroundWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = True
    autoResetEvent = New AutoResetEvent(False)
    ProgressBar = New frmProgressBar(BackgroundWorker)
    ProgressBar.ShowDialog()

    autoResetEvent.WaitOne()
    MsgBox("Main Done", vbInformation)
End Sub

Sub Processing() Handles BackgroundWorker.DoWork
    BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress(33)
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)

    BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress(66)
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)

    BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress(100)

    MsgBox("Background Done", vbInformation)
    AutoResetEvent.Set()
End Sub
```

And below is my code in for which contains progressbar:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class frmProgressBar

    Private WithEvents _BGW As System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker
    Private _TaskInProgress As String

    Public WriteOnly Property TaskInProgress()
        Set(value)
            _TaskInProgress = value
            _BGW.ReportProgress(1)
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub New(ByVal BGW As System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker)
        _BGW = BGW
        InitializeComponent()
    End Sub

    Private Sub frmProgress_Shown(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
        If Not IsNothing(_BGW) Then
            _BGW.RunWorkerAsync()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub _BGW_ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles _BGW.ProgressChanged
        progressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage

        If Me.Text <> _TaskInProgress Then
            Me.Text = _TaskInProgress
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub _BGW_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles _BGW.RunWorkerCompleted
        Me.Close()
        _TaskInProgress = ""
    End Sub

    'Private Sub _BGW_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles _BGW.DoWork
    '    Do While True
    '        ' Has the background worker be told to stop?
    '        If _BGW.CancellationPending Then
    '            ' Set Cancel to True
    '            e.Cancel = True
    '            Exit Do
    '        End If
    '        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000) ' Sleep for 1 Second
    '    Loop
    'End Sub
End Class
```

> I have uploaded my project here:
>   https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7gzonuQsNbvaDZvR3ltSl9WNTg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Oh what tangled webs we weave.  There is no obvious mistake and the posted code runs as expected.  You are ignoring the e.Error property in your RunWorkerCompeted event handler, never to that.  And get rid of that AutoResetEvent, it does nothing useful.

Comment: Could you please upload your working version somewhere? As it is still not working for me as expected.

Comment: @HansPassant Still having issues. I have uploaded my project here, can you please have a look by running at your end please? https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7gzonuQsNbvaDZvR3ltSl9WNTg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please notice that "Background Done" message box is never shown, mean the background worker is terminated somehow.

Comment: It is a lovely bug, *very* hard to diagnose.  It is caused by setting the dialog's ControlBox property to False.  That trips a bug inside Winforms when you assign the Text property, it thinks it needs to recreate the window and that causes the dialog to close.  Not assigning the Text property in your _BGW_ProgressChanged() method bypasses it.  Realistically, a dialog must *always* have a Close button and misbehaves when it doesn't.  Lots of existing Q+A here that shows you how to disable the Close button so you can set ControlBox back to True.

Comment: @HansPassant You are great! Thanks a ton. Please post this as answer if you wish, I will mark it as answer and give upvote!

Comment: I would if the question would give *any* lead to the problem.  It doesn't, there is no cue whatsoever that ControlBox = False.  It is up to you to bang this Q+A into shape so the next programmer doesn't suffer the same fatality.  Edit the question, post your own answer, flag my comment as "obsolete".

Comment: One update: I passed progress bar text in  ReportProgress method and used it though e.UserState in ProgressChaged event. And so in ProgressChanged event I was able to change form's Text property even with ControlBox=True. Strange but it's a fact!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the corrected code which worked very well:

```
Public Class frmMisc
    Private WithEvents BackgroundWorker As BackgroundWorker, ProgressBar As frmProgressBar

    Private Sub btnProgressBarPOC_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnProgressBarPOC.Click
        Call RunProcessing()

        MsgBox("Main Done", vbInformation)
    End Sub

    Sub RunProcessing()
        BackgroundWorker = New BackgroundWorker()
        BackgroundWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = True
        ProgressBar = New frmProgressBar(BackgroundWorker)
        ProgressBar.ShowDialog()
    End Sub

    Sub Processing() Handles BackgroundWorker.DoWork
        BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress(33, "Step-1")
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000)

        BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress(66, "Step-2")
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)

        BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress(100, "Step-3")
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class frmProgressBar

    Private WithEvents _BGW As System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker
    Private _TaskInProgress As String

    Public Sub New(ByVal BGW As System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker)
        _BGW = BGW
        InitializeComponent()
    End Sub

    Private Sub frmProgress_Shown(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
        If Not IsNothing(_BGW) Then
            _BGW.RunWorkerAsync()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub _BGW_ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles _BGW.ProgressChanged
        progressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage

        Me.Text = e.UserState
    End Sub

    Private Sub _BGW_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles _BGW.RunWorkerCompleted
        Me.Close()
        _TaskInProgress = ""
    End Sub
End Class
```

> I was doing up Me.Text outside of ProgressChanged even which was
>   causing this issue.
>   Thanks to @Hans for providing hint about this!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the AutoReset event as you can handle the RunWorkerCompleted event. Currently you are blocking the UI thread.

Remove the msgbox from RunWorkerAsync as well as this should be handled on your ui thread.

I suspect its an exception that is causing the RunWorkerAsync to exit so inspect the error code in the RunWorkerCompleted event. This is probably caused by your TaskInProgress property which through a roundabout way is interacting with the textbox despite being on the Background thread.

Instead to update the TaskInProgress textbox send it as the extra argument to ReportProgress and get it back from the progress box.

```
BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress(33, "Hello")

Private Sub _BGW_ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles _BGW.ProgressChanged
    Me.Text = CStr(e.UserState)
     ....
```

Comment: But if I don't implement AutoResetEvent, Main thread ends before BackgroundWorker. I need the Main thread to wait for the BackgroundWorekr to complete. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: From what I can see of your code your progress form's ShowDialog() method should block until the background worker is complete. Your main thread wont exit until you close your main form either ... it's just the button click handler that will exit

Comment: I just tried after removing AutoResetEvent. Now the RunWorkerCompleted even also never called. I had my breakpoint there and it never reached there. I think the Main thread is killing the background worker somehow.

Comment: Set a breakpoint in Processing and make sure it is starting, then see where it stops.

Comment: Hi, I set breakpoint and noticed that as soon as it reaches to Thread.Sleep statemetns, control reaches back to btnProgressBarPOC_Click function and progressbar hides. Seems like Main thread wait only if BackgroundWorker is working and not when sleeping.

Comment: That's expected, when a thread sleeps another one resumes. You need to focus on why the complete event is not firing. Try removing the sleeps, step through and see that it actually finishes the DoWork function. Make sure your handlers are connected and aren't throwing exceptions.

Comment: Still having issues. I have uploaded my project here, can you please have a look by running at your end please? https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7gzonuQsNbvaDZvR3ltSl9WNTg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please notice that "Background Done" message box is never shown, mean the background worker is terminated somehow.